# How to have both Total record count and records returned in the same SQL query

Tags: sql, count

I want to create a SQL query which will return both the total count from the table and max records; i.e. the sql will return only the maxrecords at a time like 20 records in one fetch and when user click on next page the table will display next 20 records.

I have the orderby in the end of the query, when I try to get total count I get only 20 records even when there are 1000 records in the table.

```
ORDER BY @TableSort
OFFSET @StartIndex ROWS FETCH NEXT @MaxRecords ROWS ONLY
```

Can someone provide any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: What is the schema of your expected result?

Comment: Schema is a list of records and one record (count).

Comment: That's not what "schema" means.